# Check whether I added kotlin support in my android project

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I created a project, and I'm not sure if I included Kotlin support.

[image]

How can I check if I did include it or not, and if I didn't, how can I add it after the project was created?

Comment: check https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-kotlin.html and https://medium.com/@elye.project/setup-kotlin-for-android-studio-1bffdf1362e8

Comment: I wouldn't mark it as duplicate to this question. voting to reopen.

Comment: Just try to create a new Kotkin file the same way you would create java class. Android Studio will ask you to configure Kotkin support if you didn't.

Comment: @user221256 Thank you. I can do that, but I worked hard on this project, and it would take long to copy all the code to the new project. Just wanted to know if there's an "easy way out"?

Comment: @Horay AS -> Tools -> Kotlin -> Configure Kotkin